# ASP.net MVC and connection pooling with Oracle, allowing more connections than specified in Max Pool Size

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

We are seeing more connections than specified in our Web Config for Max Pool Size.

If our settings are "Min Pool Size=2;Max Pool Size=3", why are we seeing up to 10 connections?

We are using Entity Framework and connect with the following:

private InmateEntities db = new InmateEntities();

Comment: You saw theses connection in some kind of activity monitor ? What are these looking like ?

Comment: Our DBA says that he can see them from the Oracle side of things. He can see up to 10 connections from the user we connect to the database with.

Comment: I have at least 3 connections for a single request, if you have several request at the time it might be normal.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure not to mistake processes and connections, i tested it and here is what i have for the most simple query :

[image]

There are 3 processes running, but comming from a single session ID.

One session ID = one connection

If you have multiple session ID for a single query, then yes, it would be very weird.