# Why is entity creating 3 processes for a single query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I was wondering, because when I look into my activity monitor, I see 3 processes for one little query. I know Entity has its complicated way, but I was really wondering :

Why do I see 3 processes running for my single entity framework request?

[image]

**Edit**

The query is the following :

```
using (DAL.GPIEntities db = new DAL.GPIEntities())
{
   List<GPM_E_DAN> l_freq = db.GPM_E_DAN.Where(t => t.FICHE == 104679).ToList();
}
```

Which returns one single row because `FICHE` is unique.

**Edit**

SQL profiler shows this, for one query :

[image]

Five lines related to ACCESS_GPI.

**Edit**

Ok, the query produced by Entity is a select with 50 fields, because there IS 50 fields in the table, but i'll show you the 3 first fields :

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[FICHE] AS [FICHE], 
[Extent1].[ORG] AS [ORG], 
[Extent1].[ID_ECO] AS [ID_ECO]

FROM (SELECT 
      [GPM_E_DAN].[FICHE] AS [FICHE], 
      [GPM_E_DAN].[ORG] AS [ORG], 
      [GPM_E_DAN].[ID_ECO] AS [ID_ECO], 
) AS [Extent1]
WHERE 104678 = [Extent1].[FICHE]
```

Copied the whole query and pasted it in a blank page, after running it manualy in SQL Management Studio, here is my monitor :

[image]

Only one process is related to GPI...

Comment: There's only one connection. The first column is the session ID, and it's the same for all three. One session, one connection. However, you can certainly have more than one *task* per session, when parallelism gets involved (or possibly MARS, but I have little experience with MARS -- I think EF uses it, though). A more pertinent question would be: what's the "one little query"?

Comment: the "little query" as been added to my question, thanks for making me notice that it's 3 processes and not 3 connections

Comment: It's possible the first two queries are because of Entity Framework first load (it check twice in the __MigrationHistory table)? You should run SQL profiler instead and report the SQL generated.

Comment: If you run your query twice, on a new instance of the context, do you get 3 more processes, or just 1?

Comment: There seems to always be 3 processes no matter how big is the query, and even if i run it 4 times it is still 3 process, added sql profiler in the question

Comment: That looks fine, only one query is running (the one on session 536). If you want more details on the waiting tasks, query [`sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/updated-sys-dm_os_waiting_tasks-script/). It's not EF that's creating these tasks, in any case, it's the query engine. You could study the execution plan of the query to see if there are parallel operations involved.

Comment: Thanks anyway, i really think it's Entity Framework that at least use 3 task, (i don't know the reason why) someone else had a similar question and he is still searching ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243322/asp-net-mvc-and-connection-pooling-with-oracle-allowing-more-connections-than-s/40269083#40269083

Comment: Copy the query you captured with sql profiler and run it from ssms. It will behave the same way. As Jeroen told you, it is the query engine that employs parallelism. Study the query plan carefully and make sure it isn't forced to run table scans due to a lack of indices or similar.

Comment: @9Rune5 I edited my question... see, it dosen't makes more sens... Has anyone been able to run an EF6 query and have only one process running ? I'm seriously having doubts rigth now... Maybe it's just me, i don't know.

Comment: Probably EF uses parallelism like everyone says, maybe it is using parallelism no matter how big is the task, it's hard to tell. But right now i can't beleive something else.